# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process'

Tags: wpf, windows-community-toolkit

I am showing this notification to the user when I finish doing some work.

I manage to send the notification to the user, but it doesn't open the document that I am sending it

What I am trying to do, is open the document in word on your local compuuter

```
  speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (sender, e) => {

                    const string ext = ".docx";

                    var pathToSave = CreateFolderService.CreateFolder(ConstantsHelpers.TRANSCRIPTIONS);

                    var filename = Path.Combine(pathToSave, $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath)}{ext}");

                    var sb = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (var item in Characers) {
                        sb.Append(item);
                    }

                    using var document = new WordDocument();

                    document.EnsureMinimal();

                    document.LastParagraph.AppendText(sb.ToString());

                    // Find all the text which start with capital letters next to period (.) in the Word document.

                    //For example . Text or .Text

                    TextSelection[] textSelections = document.FindAll(new Regex(@"[.]\s+[A-Z]|[.][A-Z]"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < textSelections.Length; i++) {

                        WTextRange textToFind = textSelections[i].GetAsOneRange();

                        //Replace the period (.) with enter(\n).

                        string replacementText = textToFind.Text.Replace(".", ".\n\n");

                        textToFind.Text = replacementText;

                    }

                    document.Save(filename);

                    ToastService.LaunchToastNotification(filename);

                    tiles![Id].IsTileActive = true;
```

public static void LaunchToastNotification(string FilePath) {

```
        ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs => {
            // Obtain the arguments from the notification
            ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);
            Process.Start(FilePath, args["doc"]);
        };

        new ToastContentBuilder()
            .AddText(Lang.ToastMsg1)
            .AddText(Lang.ToastMsg2)
            .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("file:///" + Path.GetFullPath(@"Images\Word.png"), UriKind.Absolute), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle)
            .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                .SetContent("Open document")
                .AddArgument("action", "openDec")
                .AddArgument("doc", FilePath))
            .Show();
```

I get an exception

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:

'An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid\Documents\TreanscribeMe\Transcriptions\Why French Makes No Sense pt 120 Accents.docx' with working directory

'C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\TranscribeMe\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'

Witch makes no sense to me, because, I am sending the file path

C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Madrid\Documents\TreanscribeMe\Transcriptions\Why French Makes No Sense pt 120 Accents.docx

Also for some reason, the notification is triggered twice

This is my Toast Service

```
 public class ToastService {

        public static void LaunchToastNotification(string FilePath) {

            ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs => {
                // Obtain the arguments from the notification
                ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);
                Process.Start(FilePath, args["doc"]);
            };

            new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddText(Lang.ToastMsg1)
                .AddText(Lang.ToastMsg2)
                .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("file:///" + Path.GetFullPath(@"Images\Word.png"), UriKind.Absolute), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle)
                .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                    .SetContent("Open document")
                    .AddArgument("action", "openDec")
                    .AddArgument("doc", FilePath))
                .Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Update

I am doing this now

```
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs => {
                // Obtain the arguments from the notification
                ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);
                Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", args["doc"]);
            };

            new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddText(Lang.ToastMsg1)
                .AddText(Lang.ToastMsg2)
                .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("file:///" + Path.GetFullPath(@"Images\Word.png"), UriKind.Absolute), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle)
                .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                    .SetContent("Open document")
                    .AddArgument("action", "openDec")
                    .AddArgument("doc", FilePath))
                .Show();
```

and get
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'A key with name 'doc' could not be found.'

Second update

I change a little to

```
            ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs => {
                // Obtain the arguments from the notification
                ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
                startInfo.Arguments = FilePath;
                startInfo.Arguments = "doc";
                Process.Start(startInfo);
```

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'WINWORD.EXE' with working directory 'C:\Users\egome\source\repos\TranscribeMe\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Yes you are sending a file path but what is `ToastService`?  It would appear it is trying to open the document.  I think we would need to see the implementation of `ToastService.LaunchToastNotification`  Or does the error occur when you create the new WordDocument?

Comment: Ok I will just a sec

Comment: So you are using `Process.Start` on the word document path.  Now I don't now if that's legal or if it is supposed to automatically detect from the file extension that word is the default handler of all .DOCX files but the way to do this might be to launch word.exe and use the file as the argument.  That, at least, is typically how I start things like, say, NotePad to open files when I use Process.Start

Comment: Could you write an example please, and why is the notification triggering twice

Comment: I put an update

Comment: Well then, the odds are that winword.exe is not in your current path.  Not hard to determine.  Make your process write the value of `Environment.ProcessPath` to your log.   examine that path.  Do any of the directories contain MS Word's executable?  If not, you need to find the full path to the executable for word.  And by the way, your example first sets the value of `startInfo.Arguments` to `FilePath` and then completely overwites it with the string "doc".  Why?

Comment: Because the toast has the argument of "doc"

Comment: Yes but in the line immediately before that one you already set Arguments.  So that line has the effect of undoing what the line before it did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248574/discussion-between-eduardo-gomez-and-joe).